# Highcharts: cannot amend the histogram tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am struggling to format the tooltip on a highcharts histogram chart. For some reason, the bins are presented to the 10th decimal point, which is very unhelpful... Please see image below.

```
How do I amend the tooltip so that it is rounded to 2 decimal points?
```

I tried messing with the 'point.key' configuration, but it only allows me to amend the first number, and not the second.

[image: My issue with the highcharts histogram]

Answer (score 3):

You can set the [tooltip.pointFormat](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bellcurve.tooltip.pointFormat) to display values with two decimal places.

The default format for a histogram is:

```
pointFormat: `
  <span style="font-size:10px">{point.x} - {point.x2}</span<br/>
  <span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span>{series.name} <b>{point.y}</b><br/>`
```

To display values with two decimals points change `{point.x}` to `{point.x:.2f}`. See [format strings](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting) section.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/r9zwwu3j/